# Connecting mysql and c#

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0

I have been following the instructions in [the link](https://creativekeystrokeshereat.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/connecting-c-form-to-database/)  in Visual Studio 2013.
In VS 2013, there is no "Add service reference" in solution explorer -> reference. 
I'm unable to add reference of mysql through "Add reference". What should I do to complete that process in Visual Studio 2013?? or else do I have to use 2010 version??

Comment: That is a really crappy tutorial. Anyway you need "Add Reference", not "Add Service Reference". Did you install the MySQL Connector for .NET?

Comment: Yes I have installed it, but I can't find it in the particular location, Now i'm unable to uninstall that connector.net. I'm able to uninstall other soft wares.  Why is that?? Also I installed connector c++ and  I got .dll file in location, but i'm unable to add it. There is a error message "Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly and COM component". How can I make it accessible??

Answer (score 0):

"Add service reference" does not depend on Visual Studio 2013 or VS 2010 and even 2015.

It depends on which target framework you are using. You should use .NET Framework 3.0 and above to see this menu item.

But according to your [link](https://creativekeystrokeshereat.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/connecting-c-form-to-database/) you do not need to add service reference. You should download the MySQL .NET connector and add the reference to the file: 
in solution explorer select References -> Add reference -> Browse and open the folder `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.7\Assemblies\v4.5` (if you use the installation path by default) or something like that and select MySql.Data.dll. 
After that you can add `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` and use connector in your code.

Comment: Don't use, and don't suggest edits that use, `inline code` to highlight random terms. It's for inline code.

Comment: Could you please say me the file location where would it be?  I can't locate the place, but i installed the software.

Answer (score 0):

Flawed are the instructions you're looking at.

You need the MySQL installer from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/

You can customize the installer to only install the "MySQL for Visual Studio" addin version 1.2.4 and the Connector/NETversion 6.9.7. (Or you can install more stuff. But you've already installed WAMP.)

Install those things. Then you can use the Server Explorer to connect to your new MySQL database. You don't need any service references.

You can add the appropriate References for MySQL. Browse for them.  You'll find them at a path like this

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.NET 6.9\Assemblies
```

Choose the right version of dotnet (4.0, 4.5?) and then choose the DLLs you need. MySql.Data is the basic one for doing sample programs like the one in the tutorial you pointed out.

Comment: Yes, i have installed the mysql connector, but I can't find that in the above  location that you have mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried searching your drive for `MySql.Data.dll` ? That may tell you where it is installed.

Comment: sir, I planned to uninstall the sql connector and then install it again, but when i uninsntall, there is a message "MySQL Connector Net 6.9.7 Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been modified"  in the wizard. How can I uninstall the software, and then install it??